# The Fibonacci formula does not correctly output the Nth value

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Hi, here's your problem today. This problem was recently asked by
> LinkedIn:
>
> You are given a positive integer N which represents the number of
> steps in a staircase. You can either climb 1 or 2 steps at a time.
> Write a function that returns the number of unique ways to climb the
> stairs.

This problem actually produces the Fibonacci sequence:

```
1 step =1 way,
2 steps =2 ways,
3 steps =3 ways,
4 steps =5 ways,
5 steps =8 ways, 
6 steps =13 ways
7 steps =21 ways
8 steps =34 ways
9 steps =55 ways
10 steps =89 ways
11 steps =144 ways
12 steps =233 ways
13 steps =377 ways
```

So to solve this without a for loop or recursion, I decided to write the Fibonacci formula for the nth term:

```
import math

def staircase(n):
  # Fill this in.
  term_a = ((1 + math.sqrt(5))/2) ** n
  term_b = ((1 - math.sqrt(5))/2) ** n

  numerator = term_a - term_b
  denominator = math.sqrt(5)

  return int(numerator/denominator)
  
print(staircase(4))
# 3
print(staircase(5))
# 5
```

For 4 and 5, I am supposed to get 5 and 8. Instead, I'm getting 3 and 5. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well `(3, 5)` is just one pair offset from `(5, 8)` in the Fibonacci sequence... Notice that the stair-step sequence starts at `(1, 2)` and not the conventional `(0, 1)` (or `(1, 1)`, if you're a heathen) of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Seem like just sticking `n += 1` at the top of the function fixes this.

Comment: This is disagreement over whether the Fibonacci sequence starts at 0 or 1 — and it looks like you're off-by-one, hmm…

Comment: With the formula you are using F(0) and F(1) are set respectively F(0)=0 and F(1)=1. You can check this [here](https://math.hmc.edu/funfacts/fibonacci-number-formula/). Then F(2)=1, F(3)=2, F(4)=3, F(5)=5. Which is exactly what you get running your snippet

Comment: there is nothing wrong the output are corrects check the values of the sequences https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number so there is no question to answer

Comment: To clarify my first comment, the closed formula assumes a certain starting pair. The only real "answer" here is that OP is simply using the formula incorrectly.

Comment: the formula is correct and his results are corrects as well. when you say formula which one do you mean? check out the wikipedia link or add reference... there is no error in the question just mathematical misunderstanding about the sequence

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above your program do its job and perfectly described the Fibonacci sequence. Here I implement the recursive version and then compare the result with your implementation (explicit form).

```
import math

def staircase(n):

    term_a = ((1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2) ** n
    term_b = ((1 - math.sqrt(5)) / 2) ** n

    numerator = term_a - term_b
    denominator = math.sqrt(5)

    return int(numerator / denominator)


def fibo_rec(n):
    # initial conditions
    if n == 0: return 0
    if n == 1: return 1
    # recursive relationship
    return fibo_rec(n-1) + fibo_rec(n-2)

n = 20
test = [fibo_rec(i) for i in range(n)] == [staircase(i) for i in range(n)]
print(test)
```

Output

```
True
```

Comment: why a downgrade? the answer just show that there is no error in the explicit formula. Please motivate